# Provide quick-summary options for typo fixes, grammar fixes, etc

Tags: feature-request, edits, edit-summary

My personal experience is that very often, I use Edit Summary for:

1. Typos
2. Grammar Errors
3. Minor Changes  (where the essence of the information has not changed, and edit summary can hardly offer value to the reader).
4. Others (some more clarification added, genuine corrections which fix some problems with the original post etc).

Now, in the first three cases, I most often leave the summary blank, or if I am feeling hyper-responsible, I type: "typo", "grammar" or "minor".

I suggest we provide a radio button in Edit Summary, with the default set to "minor". Something like:

- Minor
- Typo
- Grammar
- Other (please explain)

This offers a quick way to describe many edits instead of blank summaries. (Of course there is one more click for someone who wants to add proper summary for the 4th case).

---

The above of course may need modification/improvements, but just wanted to convey the idea.

Comment: Actually, not sure whether Minor/Others need to be separate tags.

Comment: @JP19 Minor/Other should be separate, but Typo/Grammar might be able to be merged.